# Python multiprocessing with subprocess stops working

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, multiprocessing, permutation

Can you help me?
- **Avoid** the program to **hang** after ~16.000 permutations,
- **All processes** should **stop** if one finds the solution (see output),
- Give me **general advice to make my code better, faster and learn** more about python?

I try to brute force my True Crypt container because I forgot my password. I can still remember the words, but I miss the combination. Therefore I thought about this script.

What should it do? I hand it a word list and it should a) build all permutations and b) try if it finds the right one. Because I work on Windows 7 I use True Crypt command-line interface for trying, which I access via a python subprocess.

After writing a [single threaded version](https://github.com/lony/tc-brute-force/blob/master/TrueCryptBruteForce.py) I thought about making it faster. I first tried multiple threads then found the GIL and used multiprocessing. For me this is a learning experience, I never used Python before and know only Java and PHP. And I never did parallel programming before.

**The code:**

```
import subprocess, os, sys, time, multiprocessing, Queue, itertools

wordlist = [
"foo",
"bar",
"zoo",
"hello",
"World",
]
tcFile = r"C:\dev\tc-brute-force\test.pa"
tcProg = r"C:\Program Files\TrueCrypt\TrueCrypt.exe"
tcMountLetter = "z"
verbose = 5 # as higher as more output is shown fatal=0-5=trace
counter = 0
numberofworkers = multiprocessing.cpu_count()*2
curenttime = time.time()

def getDuration(starttime):
        return time.time() - starttime

def callTC(password, event):
    commandArgs = [
        tcProg,
        '/a',
        '/s',
        '/q',
        '/v', tcFile,
        '/l', tcMountLetter,
        '/p',  password,
    ]

    child = subprocess.Popen(commandArgs, \
        stderr=open(os.devnull, 'w'), \
        stdout=open(os.devnull, 'w'))
    result = child.communicate() # Really important to get error code!

    if verbose > 4:
        print subprocess.list2cmdline(commandArgs).rstrip() + \
            " Status out=" + str(result[0]) + \
            " err=" + str(result[1]) + \
            ", code=" + str(child.returncode)

    if child.returncode == 0:
        event.set()
        print "Successfully opened TrueCrypt file with '%s' at iteration %d, duration %.3fs" % (password, counter, getDuration(curenttime))

def callTCDaemon(queue, event):
    while True:
        if queue.empty():
            break
        else:
            password = queue.get()
            callTC(password, event)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    event = manager.Event()
    worker = manager.Queue(numberofworkers)

    # start processes
    pool = []
    for i in xrange(numberofworkers):
        process = multiprocessing.Process(target=callTCDaemon, args=(worker, event))
        process.start()
        pool.append(process)

    # generate permutations
    for x in xrange(1, (len(wordlist)+1) ):
        for permutation in itertools.permutations(wordlist, x):

            # shutdown if result is found
            if event.is_set():
                # wait till finished
                for p in pool:
                    p.join(2)

                print "Finished TrueCrypt brute-force, after %d attempts, duration %.3fs" % (counter, getDuration(curenttime))
                sys.exit(1)

            counter += 1    
            combination = ""

            # build string from permutation
            for i in range(0, len(permutation)):
                combination += permutation[i]

            # output progress
            if verbose == 4 and counter%100 == 0:
                print "%15d|%15.3fs: %s" % (counter, getDuration(curenttime), combination)

            # avoid queue overload
            while worker.qsize() > 100:
                if verbose > 3: print "Wait because queue is full, size=%d" % (worker.qsize)
                time.sleep(4)           

            worker.put(combination)
```

Example output (altered a bit):

```
C:\dev\tc-brute-force>python TrueCryptBruteForceProcesses.py
            100|         23.013s: fooWorld
            200|         48.208s: barHelloWorld
Successfully opened TrueCrypt file with 'Worldfoo' at iteration 0, duration 50.218s
Successfully opened TrueCrypt file with 'Worldbar' at iteration 0, duration 50.249s
Successfully opened TrueCrypt file with 'Worldzoo' at iteration 0, duration 50.260s
Successfully opened TrueCrypt file with 'Worldhello' at iteration 0, duration 50.304s
Successfully opened TrueCrypt file with 'foobarzoo' at iteration 0, duration 50.354s
Successfully opened TrueCrypt file with 'helloWorld' at iteration 0, duration 50.433s
Successfully opened TrueCrypt file with 'foobarhello' at iteration 0, duration 50.438s
Successfully opened TrueCrypt file with 'foobarWorld' at iteration 0, duration 50.440s
Successfully opened TrueCrypt file with 'foozoobar' at iteration 0, duration 50.473s
Finished TrueCrypt brute-force, after 209 attempts, duration 50.733s
```

Comment: unrelated: GIL has no effect on subprocesses. In your case one password corresponds to one truecrypt subprocess. If the time that it takes to spawn a new subprocess is much larger than everything else in your script then there is no point to use `multiprocessing` instead of threads.

Comment: measure it (if you remove the word `.dummy` in my answer then it uses processes instead of threads).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three main parts in the brute-force code:

- generate passwords
- check a single password
- check many passwords concurrently

#### Generate passwords

Yield all possible permutations:

```
import itertools

def generate_passwords(wordlist):
    for password_length in range(1, len(wordlist) + 1): # no repeats
        for password in itertools.permutations(wordlist, password_length):
            yield " ".join(password)
```

#### Check password

Look at [TRUECRYPT EXPLAINED](http://blog.bjrn.se/2008/01/truecrypt-explained.html). Maybe you don't need to spawn a subprocess for each password.

```
from subprocess import call

def valid_password(password):
    rc = call(true_crypt_command(password), close_fds=True)
    return rc == 0, password
```

#### Check many password concurrently

```
import sys
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool # use threads

wordlist = "foo bar zoo hello World".split()
pool = Pool(20) # check 20 passwords in parallel
for i, (found, password) in enumerate(
    pool.imap_unordered(valid_password, generate_passwords(wordlist))):
    if i % 1000 == 0: # report progress
       sys.stderr.write("\rchecked %d" % i)
    if found:
       print("Found: '%s'" % password)
       break
else:
    sys.exit("failed to find")

pool.close() 
####pool.join() # uncomment if it is not the end
```

Except for `true_crypt_command()` function that generates TrueCrypt command line, it is the full source.

Another code example: [Brute force http basic auth](https://gist.github.com/zed/0a8860f4f9a824561b51).

> Will imap_unordered stop all the other threads/processes if one reaches rc==0?

If you exit the program immediately after the `break` then OS kills all remaining threads automatically (they are daemon thread so they won't survive).

If your program continues to run after the loop then upto 20 threads (size of the pool) might continue to run. You can wait for them to end if you uncomment `pool.join()`.

Comment: Nice, thank you. I always thought that I somehow have to control the itertools, because if I don't it will overflow the memory. Will imap_unordered stop all the other threads/processes if one reaches rc==0?

Comment: Finally I had time to test it. Really nice code! I especially like the yield, something new to me. Still there are two problems, a) the yield returns no longer sorted permutations (length) and b) if the success is reached the returned password is not the one used. Do you know how I can change this?

Comment: Without dummy the code is one sec faster for my test file. https://github.com/lony/tc-brute-force/blob/master/TrueCryptBruteForceProcesses.py <-- thats the refactored code

Comment: Correction, "imap_unordered" is the problem. But even if I use just "imap" it is not guaranteed that the success message shows the "right" password. Do you know how I can make sure that the thread who finds the password also returns it in time to show it?

Comment: @lony: `imap_unordered` is the right function if you want to exit as soon as possible. It gives you results as soon as they are available. It is *not* the same order that `generate_passwords()` produces. The loop prints the first password that caused your truecrypt command to return exit status zero. Check that the command works on a test file. Why do you use `"".join(password)` instead of `" ".join(password)`? Fix indentation of your code.

Comment: @lony: about performance: `one sec faster` is not very informative. "One sec faster" if it runs an hour and "one sec faster" if it runs 2 seconds total are very different things. Instead, you could report it as: It takes 2.3 seconds to check 2718281 passwords (see `i` in the code) using threads and 1.3 seconds using processes (no `.dummy`). And the relative performance stays the same for different pool sizes on Python 2.7, Windows 7, 4 CPUs.

Comment: Thanks. The second part is clear. The first one not so much. I use "" because I want to join the word permutation to one word, without having spaces. Did I do it the wrong way? The problem I have with imap (even without unordered) is that its not returning the password that fits for my test file. I think the problem is that ones the file is mounted all calls return with rc==0 so the fastest wins. That's never the right, because it takes to long to mount the volume. Witch the others don't have to do. They check only the header. What can I do, besides coding my own mounting algo?

Comment: @lony: the issue might be that your truecrypt command returns exit status zero even if you give it *invalid password* if the volume is already mounted. Fix the command not to do that. If you can't, uncomment `pool.join()` and print to stderr passwords with `rc == 0` inside `valid_password()` (it will print around 20 of them).

Comment: @Sebastian Even if I do the second it is not printing the right statement. It seems TrueCrypt is not returning the right code at the right time. If I do it with single thread it is working with the return code. What is happening? Could it be that TrueCrypt is sooo slow that it passes the information to late somehow? Do you know if there is a TC lib for python? I don't want to incl. all the libs Björn post.

Comment: @lony: if it doesn't return zero even if you pass *valid password* then you should try a different command. You should probably ask a different question about how to check whether truecrypt password is valid regardless of whether a volume is mounted or not.

Comment: @Sebastian Good point I thought you had already tried implementing Björns idea ;) Back to this question. What if I want to communicate between the processes?

Comment: @lony: processes are already communicating: parent process sends arguments to child processes and receives back the results. Communicating between child processes will fix the issue only if you serialize all commands and it defeats the purpose of using `multiprocessing` here. You could try to copy the truecrypt volume header several times and access each file strictly sequentially (the only parallelism is from decrypting different files in parallel).

Comment: Thanks I thought about that too. But I think this is out of my league. I now try do use your approach but size down my permutations. Thanks a lot for your help! I learned a lot.